Why is my view not updating using MVVM architecture?
I have two Swift UI views, CategoriesListView and CategoryView. CategoriesListView works sort of like a navigation menu and CategoryView is a view that can be tapped. I'm trying to attempt the following:

All the categories start off un-highlighted except the first category.
If user selects one of the categories in the list (CategoryView is selected), that category displays a highlighted image
Whatever category was selected before gets un-highlighted and displays an un-highlighted image

Unfortunately once something is tapped, the category views don't get changed. Do I have to do something in the view model? I am pretty new to SwiftUI and am still learning a lot
my views:
struct CategoriesListView: View {
    @Environment(CategoriesListViewModel.self) var categoriesListViewModel
    
    var selectedIndex: Int { categoriesListViewModel.categories.firstIndex(where: {
            $0.isSelected == true
        }) ?? 0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var categoriesListViewModel = categoriesListViewModel
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 12) {
                Spacer()
                // With each category in the categories list view model, create a category view. If the category view gets tapped, change that view to be the selected image. the previously selected view shows an unselected image.
                ForEach(Array(categoriesListViewModel.categories.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
                    CategoryView(categoryViewModel: $categoriesListViewModel.categories[index]).onTapGesture {
                        categoriesListViewModel.categories[selectedIndex].isSelected = false
                        categoriesListViewModel.categories[index].isSelected = true
                        CategoryView(categoryViewModel: $categoriesListViewModel.categories[index])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CategoryView: View {
    @Binding var categoryViewModel: CategoryViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        if categoryViewModel.isSelected {
            categoryViewModel.category.highlightedIconImage
        } else {
            categoryViewModel.category.iconImage
        }
    }
}

my view models:

@Observable
class CategoriesListViewModel {
    var categories: [CategoryViewModel] = []
    var currentSelection: Int = 0
    var previousSelection: Int? = nil
    
    init(categories: [CategoryViewModel], currentSelection: Int, previousSelection: Int? = nil) {
        self.categories = setCategoriesToShow()
        self.currentSelection = currentSelection
        self.previousSelection = previousSelection
    }
    
    func setCategoriesToShow() -> [CategoryViewModel] {
        var categoriesToShow = [CategoryViewModel]()
        let resortCategory = Category(
            identifier: "a",
            title: "Resort",
            outfits: [],
            iconImage: Image("ResortUnselected"),
            highlightedIconImage: Image("ResortSelected")
        )
        
        var europeCategory = Category(
            identifier: "b",
            title: "Europe",
            outfits: [],
            iconImage: Image("EuropeUnselected"),
            highlightedIconImage: Image("EuropeSelected")
        )
        
        var brunchCategory = Category(
            identifier: "c",
            title: "Brunch",
            outfits: [],
            iconImage: Image("BrunchUnselected"),
            highlightedIconImage: Image("BrunchSelected")
        )
        
        var athleisureCategory = Category(
            identifier: "d",
            title: "Athleisure",
            outfits: [],
            iconImage: Image("AthleisureUnselected"),
            highlightedIconImage: Image("AthleisureSelected")
        )
        
        var workCategory = Category(
            identifier: "e",
            title: "Work",
            outfits: [],
            iconImage: Image("WorkUnselected"),
            highlightedIconImage: Image("WorkSelected")
        )
        
        categoriesToShow.append(CategoryViewModel(category: resortCategory, isSelected: true))
        categoriesToShow.append(CategoryViewModel(category: europeCategory, isSelected: false))
        categoriesToShow.append(CategoryViewModel(category: brunchCategory, isSelected: false))
        categoriesToShow.append(CategoryViewModel(category: athleisureCategory, isSelected: false))
        categoriesToShow.append(CategoryViewModel(category: workCategory, isSelected: false))
        
        return categoriesToShow
    }
}

class CategoryViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var category: Category
    var isSelected: Bool
    
    init(category: Category, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.category = category
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}


Do not mix ObservableObject and @Observable (eg your CategoryViewModel).
Also when you use Identifiable you need to have a let id....
Try this approach cleaning up the ForEach in CategoriesListView and removing the @Bindable var categoriesListViewModel = categoriesListViewModel
 ForEach(Array(categoriesListViewModel.categories.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
     CategoryView(categoryViewModel: categoriesListViewModel.categories[index])
         .onTapGesture {
         categoriesListViewModel.categories[selectedIndex].isSelected = false
         categoriesListViewModel.categories[index].isSelected = true
     }
 }

or without using index, much better and recommended
        ForEach(categoriesListViewModel.categories) { category in
            CategoryView(categoryViewModel: category)
                .onTapGesture {
                    // turn off all selections
                    categoriesListViewModel.categories.forEach{
                        $0.isSelected = false
                    }
                    // turn on only this one
                    category.isSelected = true
                }
        }

and
@Observable
 class CategoryViewModel: Identifiable {
     let id = UUID()
     var category: Category
     var isSelected: Bool
     
     init(category: Category, isSelected: Bool) {
         self.category = category
         self.isSelected = isSelected
     }
 }

struct CategoryView: View {
    var categoryViewModel: CategoryViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        if categoryViewModel.isSelected {
            categoryViewModel.category.highlightedIconImage
        } else {
            categoryViewModel.category.iconImage
        }
    }
}

This is assuming you have have declared
@State private var model = CategoriesListViewModel(....) in your view hierarchy
and pass this model down using .environment(model)
EDIT-1
Ok, if you have tens of thousands of categories, then processing may take a few milliseconds
in a forEach loop. The following more efficient
code uses an extra var to keep track of which category to turn off, instead of using the ugly forEach loop.
struct CategoriesListView: View {
    @Environment(CategoriesListViewModel.self) var categoriesListViewModel
    @State private var prev: CategoryViewModel? // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 12) {
                Spacer()
                ForEach(categoriesListViewModel.categories) { category in
                    CategoryView(categoryViewModel: category)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            // turn on the category
                            category.isSelected = true
                            // turn off prev category
                            prev?.isSelected = false
                            // register the new prev
                            prev = category
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // since you set the currentSelection=0
            prev = categoriesListViewModel.categories.first  // <--- here
        }
    }
}


The id in the ForEach should be based on the element’s id and not the offset, right?

Not in this case, you could use id: \.0 which should be the same as id: \.offset
in this particular case. The better option is to use ForEach(categoriesListViewModel.categories)

you could also use id: \.1.id, but since the Array is simple, I don't see the benefit in this particualr case. In general avoid using this enumerated() setup and use ForEach(categoriesListViewModel.categories){...}

I like your solution of not using index because it looks clean, but I wonder if it's less efficient, since you're running a forEach inside a forEach

Ok, updated my answer using a more efficient approach if you are concerned about the processing time of the forEach loop.

In SwiftUI the View structs are the view model already (you don't need your own objects) and dynamic view data like selection should be @State that is separate from the model, e.g.
@State var selectedCategory: Category?

var body: some View {
    List(selection: $selectedCategory) {
        ForEach(model.categories) {
    ...

body is called when the selection changes.
